# PHP google map get Latitude and Longitude by type

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, google-maps

Hi guys anybody know how to get latitude and longitude by type on google map using PHP or Javascript?

for example, I want to get all restaurant on this location:

**location**: *United Kingdom, devon*

**type**:*restaurant*

it should return **name of restaurant**, **latitude**, **longitude**.

any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: another example for this would be:

location: United kingdom
type: airport

Comment: That is the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/).  However, it won't return _all_ places(unless it is limited to a small area).  It will return 200 locations (radar search) or up to 60 locations with more information in groups of 20.

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
 $(function () {
         var lat = 44.88623409320778,
             lng = -87.86480712897173,
             latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
             image = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png';

         //zoomControl: true,
         //zoomControlOptions: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,

         var mapOptions = {
             center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
             zoom: 13,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
             panControl: true,
             panControlOptions: {
                 position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
             },
             zoomControl: true,
             zoomControlOptions: {
                 style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                 position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_left
             }
         },
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions),
             marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: latlng,
                 map: map,
                 icon: image
             });

         var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
         var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
             types: ["geocode"]
         });

         autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
         var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

         google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function (event) {
             infowindow.close();
             var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
             if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                 map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
             } else {
                 map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                 map.setZoom(17);
             }

             moveMarker(place.name, place.geometry.location);
             $('.MapLat').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
             $('.MapLon').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
         });
         google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
             $('.MapLat').val(event.latLng.lat());
             $('.MapLon').val(event.latLng.lng());
             infowindow.close();
                     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                     geocoder.geocode({
                         "latLng":event.latLng
                     }, function (results, status) {
                         console.log(results, status);
                         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                             console.log(results);
                             var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                                 lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
                                 placeName = results[0].address_components[0].long_name,
                                 latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

                             moveMarker(placeName, latlng);
                             $("#searchTextField").val(results[0].formatted_address);
                         }
                     });
         });

         function moveMarker(placeName, latlng) {
             marker.setIcon(image);
             marker.setPosition(latlng);
             infowindow.setContent(placeName);
             //infowindow.open(map, marker);
         }
     });
```

Working demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DXkZJ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML AND JS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="default.css"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Places search box</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));
  map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('target'));
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  var markers = [];

  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }

    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var image = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
    <style>
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="panel">
      <input id="target" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

AND CSS

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map-canvas, #map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
}

@media print {
  html, body {
    height: auto;
  }

  #map-canvas, #map_canvas {
    height: 650px;
  }
}

#panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -180px;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

REFER HERE FOR MORE ! [GOOGLE PLACES](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)